# Omnet++ : Could not determine GDB version using command: lldbmi2 --version dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/LLDB.framework/LLDB

Tags: omnet++

I tried to debug a script on omnet++ getting the following message:

`Could not determine GDB version using command: lldbmi2 --version dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/LLDB.framework/LLDB Reason: image not found`

Can you help me?

PS: i am using MacBook Air with Catalina version 10.15.7 . I don't have Xcode installed

Comment: well, to debug with `LLDB.framework` on Mac you have to install `Xcode`, so do it and then run `xcode-select --install` in a terminal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you use:

```bash
otool -l lldvmi2 | grep path
```

You will see that the `@rpath` is referred to `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks`, this means `xcode-select --install` is not enough, you have to download the Xcode and put in `/Applications`.

I think this maybe a bug.